# SVN client error "The server at [...] does not support the HTTP/DAV protocol"

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn, subversive

I am updating from Windows 7 to a Windows 10 on a 64 bit system. I have no problems updating and checking out projects from the Subversion server on the Windows 7 box. I downloaded the latest 64 bit version and installed it on the Windows 10 box with no issues.

On the Windows 10 box I can post an update, but I cannot check out a project from the repository.  When I attempt to logon the server I get the following error message:

```
svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://svn.example.com/!/%23MyRepo/'
svn: E175003: The server at 'https://svn.example.com/!/%23MyRepo/' does not support the HTTP/DAV protocol
```

message that says The server does not support the HTTP/DAV protocol.

I passed the error message to the server manager and was told the problem was with the TortoiseSVN app settings.  I cannot find a setting in the app that would address the problem.

Anyone have any suggestions on how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You get this error message because the URL is invalid. It leads to a web interface (i.e. a web client) and Subversion clients do not know how to parse this URL. Please, see the following article - [KB102: Subversion client errors caused by inappropriate repository URL](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00102/).

Comment: Less than helpful. Referenced page mentions "VisualSVN Server web interface". What's that?

Comment: @steve it's a web client for Subversion repositories. The error from the question occurs when a user enters a web UI URL instead of repository URL. To solve the error, you need to use a correct URL in your Subversion client.

Comment: In the web app, there's button to copy the correct URL for the repository

Answer (score 13):

The comment by Bahrep is the correct answer, but since in the comments there seems to be some confusion, I decided to elaborate further.
"The error indicates that the URL used to address the repository using Subversion client is inappropriate. Most likely, the URL was copied **from the web browser's** address bar when exploring the repository through the web interface of VisualSVN Server. Subversion client programs are not capable of handling the syntax of such URLs. The appropriate URLs should be obtained by **clicking the Checkout button** in the web interface."
I got this error because I used browser link in the toroise interface, but I should instead click "copy repository url" in the svn and use that link. As simple as that!