# Connecting TortoiseSVN to VisualSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I have VisualSVN running on a stand alone windows server and running TortoiseSVN on windows on my laptop.

This all works fine, but I've now put a new copy of VisualSVN on my main server, and made it run on port 8443.

When I try checking a project out, I get "The server at 'https://example.com:8443/project' does not support the HTTP/DAV protocol". I'm guessing it's because one of:

1. It's a new version of VisualSVN
2. I haven't set something up correctly on VisualSVN
3. VisualSVN is running on a port rather than the default 443
4. VisualSVN is running alongside IIS

Help! I can't figure it out!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the URL is incorrect. Instead of https://example.com:8443/project, try https://example.com:8443/svn/project.

You can copy the correct repository URL from a web interface (see the article [KB102](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00102/)) or the VisualSVN Server Manager console (**Copy URL to Clipboard** command, the [Getting Started](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/getting-started/#Final-Check-Up) guide). Please also check [another my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55458927/761095) to a similar question.

PS What do you see when you navigate to the URL using a web browser? If you don't see the web interface of VisualSVN Server in a web browser, then you contact some other server. In this case you may need to do some basic troubleshooting (DNS, ports, IPs).